# ResolveEventHandler not invoked when object is created in new AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, clr, assemblies

I hope it wouldn't be a duplicate, I see plenty of similar questions, but any of them help can't help me.

I have such Method code in *nameofdll.dll*:

```
    DllMethod()
    {
       Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
       Type type = assembly.GetType("Class");
       MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Method");
       object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
       method.Invoke(...);
    }
```

and Class - constructor add AssemblyResolver

```
   class Class
   {
      public Class()
      {
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
      }
      public void Method()
      {...}
      private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
      {...}
   }
```

Till now *AssemblyResolver* is invoked when I call metod from my main app.exe which is in the same folder as *nameofdll.dll*, let's name the folder as *mainfolder* and also from powershell script in this way:

```
load dll(mainfolder + nameofdll.dll)
call DllMethod()
```

Everything works fine, but I have to unload dll which AssemblyResolver had loaded, because Method is called multiple times witch different dlls versions.

So I modified DllMethod() like that:

```
{
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Method");
   //new part
   AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
   domainSetup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
   AppDomain  Domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Class, null, domainSetup);
   object obj = Domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assembly.FullName, Class);
   method.Invoke(...);
   AppDomain.Unload(Domain);
}
```

I use
    *domainSetup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);*
because BaseDirecotry was powershell folder and CreateInstanceAndUnwrap fails to find nameofdll.dll.

And finally the problem is that everyting is ok when using app.exe, but when I called that dll method from powershell script, the AssemblyResolver wasn't invoked and immediately I got error that it could not load some dlls.

I also try to copy domain setting, and add

```
AppDomainSetup domainSetup = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation;
```

where `CurrentDomain` is domain in which AssemblyResolver works fine before, but it didn't solve the problem.